# T-SQL order by, based on other column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm stuck with a query which should be pretty simple but, for reasons unknown, my brain is not playing ball here ...

**Table:**

```
id(int) | strategy (varchar) | value (whatever)
1         "ABC"                whatevs
2         "ABC"                yeah
3         "DEF"                hello
4         "DEF"                kitty
5         "QQQ"                hurrr
```

The query should select ALL rows grouped on strategy but only one row per strategy - the one with the higest id.

In the case above, it should return rows with id 2, 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, strategy , value
FROM (
       SELECT id, strategy , value 
             ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY strategy ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
      FROM Table_Name
    ) Sub
WHERE rn = 1
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/593cf/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function to get the solution you want. Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e4ea/3)

```
with cte as
(
select 
 rank()over(partition by strategy order by id desc) as rnk,  
  id, strategy, value from myT 
)
select id, strategy, value from 
cte where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T2.id,T1.strategy,T1.value
FROM TableName T1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MAX(id) as id,strategy
 FROM TableName
 GROUP BY strategy) T2
ON T1.id=T2.id
```

Result:

```
ID  STRATEGY    VALUE
2   ABC         yeah
4   DEF         kitty
5   QQQ         hurrr
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84fcb/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, strategy , value
FROM (
       SELECT id, strategy , value 
             ,MAX(id) OVER (PARTITION BY strategy) MaxId
      FROM YourTable
    ) Sub
WHERE id=MaxId
```

Comment: the subquery adds the maximum id (aliases as maxid) of the corresponding strategy group to each row. The outer query then selects only the records where the id is the maximum id of its group.

Comment: Please *[edit]* it into the answer. Comments are no place for it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one as well:

```
SELECT id, strategy, value FROM TableName WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM TableName GROUP BY strategy
)
```

Bit depends on your data, you might get results faster with it as it does not do sorting, but by the other hand it uses IN, which can slow you down if there is many 'strategies'